# how can I create multiple dataframes in forloop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**I want to create multiple dataframe using forloop**

Here is what i've done so far

```
for x in df['Area'].unique():
    cousines=[]
    for i in Cousines:
        index = df[df['Area']==x].index
        df_x = df.loc[index]
        Rating_mean = df_x[df_x['Cousines'].str.contains(i)]['Rating'].mean()
        dict1={'Cousines':i,'Rating':Rating_mean}
        cousines.append(dict1)
    x = pd.DataFrame(cousines)
```

The problem is when I use x to create Dataframes it doesn't use it as forloop variable
And I have no other idea how to use this x as my name of DataFrame

Comment: Check the correct answer please

Answer (score 0):

Every time you create a df append it to a list:

```
dfs = []
for x in df['Area'].unique():
    cousines=[]
    for i in Cousines:
        index = df[df['Area']==x].index
        df_x = df.loc[index]
        Rating_mean = df_x[df_x['Cousines'].str.contains(i)]['Rating'].mean()
        dict1={'Cousines':i,'Rating':Rating_mean}
        cousines.append(dict1)
    dfs.append(pd.DataFrame(cousines))
```

Answer (score 0):

Half an hour later!

So, after some roaming on internet, I found perfect Answer.
This might help some people.

```
df_dic={}
for x in df['Area'].unique(): 
    index = df[df['Area']==x].index
    df_x = df.loc[index]
    
    cousines=[]
    for i in Cousines:
        
        Rating_mean = df_x[df_x['Cousines'].str.contains(i)]['Rating'].mean()
        dict1={'Cousines':i,'Rating':Rating_mean}
        cousines.append(dict1)

    df_dic["{0}".format(x)]=pd.DataFrame(cousines)
```

Now, `df_dict['Area_name']` to get Area_name dataframe

```
df_dic['Alkapuri']
```

```
    Cousines      Rating
0   NorthIndian 3.961290
1   FastFood    3.811111
2   Chinese     3.922222
3   Beverages   3.992308
4   Pizza       3.592308
5   Italian     3.890000
6   Desserts    4.033333
7   StreetFood  4.260000
8   Cafe        3.866667
9   Gujarati    3.966667
```